# Suppose set X = {1, 2, 3}. I'll define the relation R = {(1,3), (3, 1)}. Is R symmetric or not.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I would assume R is symmetric because 1, 3 and 3, 1 are swapped, but in the definition of a symmetric relation, the property must hold for all a,b in the set X. But 2 is not covered in the relation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  For $R$ to be symmetric, we must have $(b,a)\in R$ for all $a,b\in X$ such that $(a,b)\in R$

Comment: @bolermus You might be confused about the definition. The definition of symmetry is if $(a,b)\in R$, then so is $(b,a)\in R$.

Comment: If you say "the property must hold", then you really need to know what the property **is**. There are different ways in which the definition of  a symmetric relation can be worded, so show us exactly what definition you are using. (This should go in the question using the "edit" button, not in a comment.)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that 2 is not covered by the relation $R$ has no impact on the symmetry of $R$. The symmetry property doesn't say on its own whether any elements are related, only that each related pair is reversible.

If you want to be careful about it, you can make a table of all the pairs $(a,b)$ from $X\times X$ and verify that $a \mathrel{R} b \iff b \mathrel{R} a$ is satisfied:

```
a b aRb bRa (aRb <=> bRa)
-------------------------
1 1  F   F        T
1 2  F   F        T
1 3  T   T        T
2 1  F   F        T
2 2  F   F        T
2 3  F   F        T
3 1  T   T        T
3 2  F   F        T
3 3  F   F        T
```